# Identify field in the git log

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log

I ran git log, and I see this:

[image]

The line that says "hotstepper" was added to the commit message using this UI on Bitbucket:

[image]

My question is - when using `$ git log --pretty-format:`, which field can I find the hotsteppper line? It does not appear to be on the subject line or sanitized_subject line.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit message is divided into two parts, subject `%s` and body `%b`. They are separated by the first line that contains only whitespace.

```
This is my
subject

This is my body
```

You can also access both parts using the raw body `%B` field.